# How to use TypedDataTable.Rows.Find(key as object) to find a row which has a composite key?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, find, datarowcollection

I have a `TypedDataTable` called `CamerasDT` which has a composite Primary Key of `GroupId` and `CameraId`. I want to use `TypedDataTable.Rows.Find(key as object)` to return a specific row by `GroupId` and `CameraId`. I don't seem to be able to find a way to send primary key to the find function. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the one of the overloads for the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6dh4x2h%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y572) method to pass an array of Objects that corresponds to the primary key values you're searching for.

Example from the MSDN article I linked:

> The following example uses the values of an array to find a specific
>   row in a collection of DataRow objects. The method assumes that a
>   DataTable exists with three primary key columns. After creating an
>   array of the values, the code uses the Find method with the array to
>   get the particular object that you want.

```
 Private Sub FindInMultiPKey(ByVal table As DataTable)
    ' Create an array for the key values to find.
    Dim findTheseVals(2) As Object

    ' Set the values of the keys to find.
    findTheseVals(0) = "John"
    findTheseVals(1) = "Smith"
    findTheseVals(2) = "5 Main St."

    Dim foundRow As DataRow = table.Rows.Find(findTheseVals)
    ' Display column 1 of the found row.
    If Not (foundRow Is Nothing) Then
        Console.WriteLine(foundRow(1).ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

In your case you'd pass an Object array with values to search for in your GroupId and CameraId fields.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. One small question, I assume I should set the primary keys in the order they appear in the table definition, right?